# My Save Button is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-field, saveresult

I have one custom object called (FeedbackFrom__c) in that I having 10 fields, each fields having different VF Pages at page no 11, I am having one save button if I click that automatically 10 fields needs to save in the object how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wizard - [Creating a Wizard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm)

We need to create 10 VF page with one single controller.
Define each field as input field in VF pages under apex:form tag.
We need buttons prev, next, cancel on each page to navigate between the prev/next VF page or to cancel the whole operation. And Save button will going to be on last page.

Each button action we have to define in our controller which will return the page reference of the VF pages.

Define a variable of type 'FeedbackFrom__c'(Let say fbFrom) in controller and getter for it.

use that variable reference in VF page to save values in fields {!fbFrom.FieldName__c}

On Save button insert the fbForm (FeedbackFrom__c).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/66201)

Comment: @Eric yeah, you are right!